# Connecting to Active Directory From Net::LDAP Perl

Tags: linux, perl, active-directory, ldap

How to connect to Active Directory from Perl?

I am using the Net::LDAP Module.

Could you please give me some examples, that can help me get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at

- the [Net::LDAP pages on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod)
- the [Net::LDAP FAQ on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.49/lib/Net/LDAP/FAQ.pod)
- the [Net::LDAP examples on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap-0.4001/lib/Net/LDAP/Examples.pod)